# Reference request for the free loop space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I've been trying to read about the free loop space $LX:= C(\mathbb{S}^1, X)$ for a topological space $X$, that is, the space of continuous maps between $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $X$, however the only resources I seem to be finding about it are research papers that, at the moment anyway, are a little bit beyond my level of understanding.

Does anyone know of any notes or textbooks that give an introduction to the basic properties of free loop spaces and/or free loop homology? Thanks.

Comment: I think I started out with this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3107.pdf

Comment: @AlvinJin Great, thanks a lot!